# XSLT template to assign the array attribute values to Single attribute with specific separators

Tags: templates, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an incoming request which has Array element like below
*XSLT 2.0*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Header>
<OrderType>NE</OrderType>
  <PONumber>123</PONumber>
  <Reference>
   <id>PoDate</id>
   <Value>20230102</Value>
 </Reference>
 <Reference>
   <id>BuyerName</id>
   <Value>Dibrahm</Value>
 </Reference>
 <Reference>
   <id>VN</id>
   <Value>MINERALS</Value>
 </Reference>
</Header>
```

Target doesn't allow the multiple occurance hence need to assgin the data to tareget variable like below

```
<TargetSystem>
<PO>123</PO>
<TypeofOrder>NE</TypeofOrder>
 <Datanotes>~PoDate:20230102~BuyerName:Dibrahm~VNMINERALS~<Datanotes>
</TargetSystem>
```

seperating Refrence ID and value wiht **colon(:)** and the data sets starts,seperates and end by the **Tilde(~)**

I tried with simple value of select where it's giving just like the ID values . I knew it's wrong way. Tried to do with template but I am not able to finish it.

```
     <TargetSystem>
    <PO><xsl:value-of select="Header/PONumber"/></PO>
    <TypeofOrder><xsl:value-of select="Header/OrderType"/></TypeofOrder>
    <Datanotes><xsl:value-of select="Header/Reference/id" separator=":" /> <Datanotes>
   </TargetSystem>
```

I request to provide some solutionto achive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Header">
  <Datanotes>
    <xsl:value-of select="'', for $r in Reference return concat($r/id, ':', $r/Value), ''" separator="~"/>
  </Datanotes>
</xsl:template>
```

For the edited, more complex sample use e.g.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="Header">
      <TargetSystem>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </TargetSystem>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="OrderType">
      <TypeofOrder>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </TypeofOrder>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="PONumber">
      <PO>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </PO>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Reference[1]">
      <Datanotes>
    <xsl:value-of select="'', for $r in ../Reference return concat($r/id, ':', $r/Value), ''" separator="~"/>
  </Datanotes>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Reference[position() gt 1]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for the quick solutions but how to call the tempalte with in the xslt. Becaue in above sample I listed only Refrence values where I can get other attributes as well so for that particular Rerence I need to assign the tempalte and reamin stright mapping.

Comment: I have updated the request Martin. could youp  please check

Comment: `<xsl:template match="/">
    <TargetSystem>
     <PO><xsl:value-of select="Header/PONumber"/></PO>
     <TypeofOrder><xsl:value-of select="Header/OrderType"/></TypeofOrder>
      <Notes>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Header/Reference"/>
      </Notes>
    </TargetSystem>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Header">
<xsl:value-of select="'', for $r in Reference return concat($r/id, ':', $r/Value), ''" separator="~"/>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>'   tried and not working this

Comment: @HKmar, see whether the edit helps.

Comment: Seems that code added multiple tempaltes which not requried Martin. Only to that Refrence needs to be apply templates. Becaue today OrderType and PONumber can be map directly. so if we have more attributes then we shouldn't go for each attribute has templete right...

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
<xsl:template match="/Header">
    <TargetSystem>
        <Datanotes>
            <xsl:value-of select="'', Reference/string-join((id, Value), ':'), ''" separator="~"/>
        </Datanotes>
    </TargetSystem>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple way to assgin with out tempalte as well.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <TargetSystem>
      <PO>
      <xsl:value-of select="Header/PONumber"/>
      </PO>
      <TypeofOrder>
      <xsl:value-of select="Header/OrderType"/>
      </TypeofOrder>
       <Datanotes>
          <xsl:for-each select="Header/Reference">
                      <xsl:value-of select="concat('~',id,':',Value)"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
       </Datanotes>
    </TargetSystem>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does not produce the trailing `~`.